# Multiple arguments in x86 parens

Tags: x86

I've been reading some x86 assembly, and I'm very confused by this syntax:

```
movl   $0x0,(%ebx,%eax,4)
```

What does putting multiple arguments inside parentheses do? It turns out this is a difficult thing to Google.

Comment: It means: Compute the numerical address %ebx + %eax*4, then store the 32-bit doubleword 0x00000000 to the memory at that address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [GNU as manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMemory.html#i386_002dMemory): `(base, index, scale)`.  In NASM syntax, that's

```
mov   [ebx + eax*4], 0
```